# javascript browser resize

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a link which opens up a new window. It first shows up as half of the screen, then maximizes to full screen. Is it possible to avoid this, and just show the window as maximized to full screen? My problem with first scenario is some of the divs are getting resized and only on refresh they behave correctly

Thanks

Comment: You only have IE tagged as a browser. Does this issue only occur there?

Comment: Users hate it when browser windows resize themselves.

Comment: @Peppered Lemons - IE is the primary browser we use

Answer (score 0):

You could try `<a href = 'www.yoursite.com' TARGET = '_top'>`. This will open the linked document in the full body of the window, but will replace the current page you are looking at.

`<a href = 'www.yoursite.com' TARGET = '_blank'>` will work on anything that is not IE (unfortunate for you of course)

More options [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp)

**Edit:** In response to your edit. You could try something along these lines:

`window.open('www.yoursite.com','blank','fullscreen, yes');`

This will open a windo like `target = '_blank'` but also should ensure that it is full screen for IE (haven't tested though)

[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

Comment: Lemos. Yes using _top works, but when I click the link, I want it to be opened in new window. I am looking for an effect like _blank as well as _top. can this be done?